# Run Django Project on other system

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

I have developed a student website using django which includes a database(MySQL), so now I want to run this django project in another system, so how can I run this django project in another system including the database(that is MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a backup of the database and copy it to the other system. Then you can create a  requirements.txt file to get the dependencies, or you just try to run the project and look which packages are missing. The last thing you have to do is that you may change some paths to different files, you added in your Project. [This might also help you.](https://mattsegal.dev/django-portable-setup.html)
Hope I could help you!